# Determine Excel Bitness in InstallShield 2012

Tags: excel, installation, 64-bit, installshield

I am building an installation package using InstallShield 2012 for an Excel add-in. Because MS Excel has 32-bit version and 64-bit version, I need to build installation packages separately. Ideally, the set up file should be able to detect the Excel bitness (not Windows bitness) during the first few steps of the installation before files are copied to target machine. However, after some extensive research online, I haven't found a reliable way of determining Excel bitness. Anyone with some ideas, please feel free to help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the (LUA - Setup Factory) code i use: it works even if Outlook is not installed.

```
-- check if 64 bit office installed

s64_14 = Registry.GetValue(3, "Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\14.0\\Outlook","Bitness",true);
s64_15 = Registry.GetValue(3, "Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\15.0\\Outlook","Bitness",true);
s64_16 = Registry.GetValue(3, "Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\16.0\\Outlook","Bitness",true);

bl64Bit = false;

if (s64_14=="x64" or s64_15=="x64" or s64_16=="x64") then
    bl64Bit = true
end

-- check for 64-bit OS
bl64BitOS=false;
if SessionVar.Expand("%ProgramFilesFolder%") ~= SessionVar.Expand("%ProgramFilesFolder64%") then
    bl64BitOS=true
end
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. I did notice that under Outlook there is a "Bitness" value, but since I have Outlook installed, I wasn't sure whether that would still be available without Outlook. So you have tried that with Outlook never installed? (I want to rule out the situation where Outlook was installed and later uninstalled but leave the registry key already modified)

Comment: Yes it works even if Outlook has never been installed. I have not tested the situation if outlook is installed and then uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar discussion with an [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) user, you can check it out on [our forums](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=23880), the user wanted to detect the Office bitness.

Comment: You cannot rely on the "Bitness" registry key referred in your answer. This key is not present if you install from a *standalone* Excel installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should create 2 Properties to keep track of which version of Excel is installed, and then use these properties as Feature Conditions "EXCEL32_EXISTS=0". Here's the code I've used to accomplish this, initially both EXCEL32_EXISTS and EXCEL64_EXISTS are set to 0.

```
Excel_Installed=FALSE;
szKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\excel.exe";

if (RegDBKeyExist(szKey)=1) then
        Excel_Installed=TRUE;
        RegDBGetKeyValueEx ( szKey, "Path", nvType, ExcelPath, nvSize );
        SprintfMsiLog( "Found Excel @ %s", ExcelPath );

        if ( StringContains(ExcelPath, "Office11")=TRUE ) then
            Excel_Installed=FALSE;
        elseif ( SYSINFO.bIsWow64=FALSE ) then
            MsiSetProperty(hMSI, "EXCEL32_EXISTS", "1");
        elseif ( (StringContains(ExcelPath, "(x86)")=TRUE) || (StringContains(ExcelPath, "Office12")=TRUE) ) then
            MsiSetProperty(hMSI, "EXCEL32_EXISTS", "1");
        else
            MsiSetProperty(hMSI, "EXCEL64_EXISTS", "1");
        endif;
endif;


export prototype BOOL StringContains(STRING,STRING);
function BOOL StringContains(szSource, szArgs)
    BOOL bContains;
begin

    if(szSource % szArgs) then
        bContains = TRUE;
    else
        bContains = FALSE;
    endif;

    return bContains;
end;
```